# ISPN000026: Caught exception purging data container

Tags: spring-boot, infinispan

I am developing a Spring Boot application using Infinispan as cache solution for the cluster server in production.

Gradle Dependencies:  (springboot version = 2.3.3.RELEASE)

```
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
  implementation "org.infinispan:infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded:2.3.3.Final"
  compileOnly    "org.infinispan:infinispan-component-annotations:10.1.8.Final"
```

Partial source code:

```
    GlobalConfigurationBuilder global = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
    String cacheLocation = "/data";
    global.globalState().enable().persistentLocation(cacheLocation);
    DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(global.build());

    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder
      .clustering()
      .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC)
      .expiration()
        .maxIdle(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .locking()
        .isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ)
      .persistence()
        .passivation(false)
        .addSingleFileStore()
          .preload(true)
          .shared(false)
          .fetchPersistentState(true)
          .ignoreModifications(false)
          .purgeOnStartup(false)
          .location("cache")
          .async()
            .enabled(true);

    Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE)
            .getOrCreateCache("myCache", infinispanConfig);
```

However I get the warning below each minute:

```
 23:15:10.291 [WARN ] org.infi.PERSISTENCE - ISPN000026: Caught exception purging data container!
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.infinispan.persistence.spi.AdvancedCacheExpirationWriter.purge(AdvancedCacheExpirationWriter.java:59)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.async.AdvancedAsyncCacheWriter.purge(AdvancedAsyncCacheWriter.java:20)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.lambda$purgeExpired$9(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:527)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.purgeExpired(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:530)
    at org.infinispan.expiration.impl.ClusterExpirationManager.processExpiration(ClusterExpirationManager.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.expiration.impl.ExpirationManagerImpl$ScheduledTask.run(ExpirationManagerImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I remove the code `.async()enabled(true)` it works, but everything is synchronized and it is not what I want. Furthermore I am getting errors when a node leaves or enters in the cluster too. I am getting lots of error using Infinispan + Spring + Cluster Mode.

I would like to use **CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC** with the ***write-behind*** (async()enabled(true)) feature, but I get also another errors such as "ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 0 milliseconds"

The directory above called "/data" is located on my local Windows and it is on my HD. It is not a shared, samba or NFS directory. I can see that the cache files are being created correctly.

I do not want suppress the warning. I expect to fix the issue.

Please, Help.
Thank you!

Comment: I have same error using infinispan 9.4.18 on EJB/CDI stack. The only difference that I see is that mine is coming from the expiration-thread, while yours it is not clearly stated.

Comment: @joccafi did you find any solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem with Qarkus and embedded-infinispan.

Comment: @FredrikAngellMoe No solution. My team decided to remove Infinispan from the project. Too risky with this kind of errors and very bad behaviour. Take a look on Apache Kafka Streams.